# Plugins for intercepting methods with a negative sort order?

Tags: magento2, plugin, interceptor

Within your `di.xml` you can add plugins to intercept methods of injectable classes. You can also specify a `sortOrder`. Can this ordering be negative, like `-1`? We guess so, but would like to know if somebody dealt with this before.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this ordering be negative, like -1?

Yes , the values can be negative

```
/* Path */ framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php

=> uasort($plugins, [$this, '_sort']);
```

**uasort** — Sort an array with a user-defined comparison function and maintain index association

```
/**
 * Sort items
 *
 * @param array $itemA
 * @param array $itemB
 * @return int
 */
protected function _sort($itemA, $itemB)
{
    if (isset($itemA['sortOrder'])) {
        if (isset($itemB['sortOrder'])) {
            return $itemA['sortOrder'] - $itemB['sortOrder'];
        }
        return $itemA['sortOrder'];
    } elseif (isset($itemB['sortOrder'])) {
        return $itemB['sortOrder'];
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**sortOrder** loads the classes loads accordingly, 
Hope this helps..:)